# html text with sound effects

Tags: html, flash, audio, effect

my sister asked me to do smth for her that let me scratch my head: she wants to make a signature text in a forum and wants to add sound to this signature so when her post is shown the sound will play in background together with her text signature.

I'm not sure this could be done in flash? is there a way to have some jpeg image with sound effect? or should it be a video? maybe forums restrict adding a flash doc as a signature?

any ideas to help make my little sister happy ;)

Comment: Besides this being an incredibly bad idea, you'll have to deal with the forum site hopefully blocking javascript within posts, if not Flash as well.

Comment: Little sisters should be teased, not pleased.

Comment: @steve yeah ,they always ask strange things that are sometimes impossible. the problem is how i could explain to her this can't be done? i beleive she will be the one who will tease me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the flash up and running, and you can't upload this swf to the forum as the signature, the only way to manage this is the forum let's you to use some embed code as the signature. Even then you have to find out where to put the swf content.

On the other hand you have to understand, that if a user would be able to attach any "active content" to his/her signature, the user could easily attach some code too, what could be a problem.

Imagine, you are watching a profile and while listening to the music 1000 popups would show up. So no flishy-flashy, no js and no nothing, that would be a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in flash, or you can use html5 audio tags.

But forums usually filter out flash embed tags, and probably would do the same with the audio tag, and if the forum your sister posts on doesn't do it, this would certainly cause them to start.  Depending on the forum, she could also end up banned, since embedding sound in a page is usually consider very annoying.

For the happiness of your sister, don't do this.

Comment: i think the site forum offers option for html code and php code. can you tell what html5 audio tag i can use to play the sound? thanks

Comment: You would just use the `<audio>` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio  As a side note, not all browsers support it yet, and there may be other things to look out for.